# MySQL - Reference data from one table to another table

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to connect tables by listing an id from another table into a specific field in a row in another table.

This is what I'm trying to do;

Table Items

```
Id   Name    Price
 1   Drink   5
 2   Food    3
```

Table Character

```
Id   Name   Cash   Inventory 
 1   Foo    10     1
 2   Bar    10     2
 3   Stu    10     1, 2
```

I am trying to reference the Items so that when I pull data concerning the Character 'Stu'
It pulls the data associated with Items '1 & 2' because he has them in his Inventory.

I've read up on Normalization and Foreign Keys but haven't been able to find a way to tie them together in the fashion I want. I've also found the INT field will not accept multiple comma separated integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easy using FIND_IN_SET looking at your table strructure here is the solution

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM `characters` as c
LEFT JOIN items as i on FIND_IN_SET(i.id, c.Inventory)
WHERE c.name= 'Stu'
```

EDIT :

Here is the edited solution means one line solution.

```
SELECT 
    c.* ,
    group_concat(i.name) as ItemName,
    group_concat(i.price) as ItemPrices         
FROM `characters` as c
LEFT JOIN items as i on FIND_IN_SET(i.id, c.Inventory)
WHERE c.name= 'Stu'
group by c.name
```

If you are using php you can explode cell with php explode function and then loop through the cell to access all the cell values.

EDIT :

```
SELECT 
    c.* ,
    group_concat(i.id) as ItemIds,
    group_concat(i.name) as ItemName,
    group_concat(i.price) as ItemPrices         
FROM `characters` as c
LEFT JOIN items as i on FIND_IN_SET(i.id, c.Inventory)
WHERE c.name= 'Stu'
group by c.name
```

Comment: I believe the first would do what need but I'm not sure about reading comma separated values in the field. I don't it would work as a VARCHAR and INT rejects it.

Comment: yes inventory field should be varchar instead of int but items id can be int

Comment: So the second solution does what I want but it only reads the first item listed in the Inventory field. 2 doesn't get read.

Comment: it reads both the records but gives you the result in a single set as you may have noticed that it displays the result as comma seperate fields i am taking about itemName and itemPrice

Comment: I see the fields and it pulls the data associated with the first referenced id '1' but '2' isn't displayed.

Comment: Ok. I can see what it's doing now. It's adding both items to the fields. Is it possible to dynamically create new Id, Name and Price fields per item?

So that each item is listed individually.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically? the usuall practice is this that you create all the items from backend (admin) now when a character is created all the items should be available to be selected(multiple selections is possible in you case ) and the multiple item ids are saved with the character using comma seperated

Comment: By dynamically I mean if the character has items 1 and 2 could it create another field called ItemName2, Item Prices2. But I see that this may work better for me in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to build one to many relationship. You need to place the foreign key into table items, i.e., CharacterId . Then you can pull data with JOIN.

Comment: That makes sense. However will this CharacterId column allow me to add multiple entries? So multiple Characters can own that item.
Or will this create new entries in the Items table for each Character who purchases that item?

Comment: You mean many-to-many relationship, if you want multiple Characters link to multiple Items. You need a join table for this relationship and there are many good guides on Internet. http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/many-to-many.html